# Best version of Plex to run on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: pi-4

I'd like some help selecting the ideal Plex Media Server installation method for a raspberry pi 4b.

I have installed the Snap before and it worked well.
There's the Armv7 deb file I could download from Plex directly as well.

I do not mind the downside of Snaps, which appear to be only in space taken and startup times, both of which aren't a concern since the pi will be running 24/7 and has a 14tb HDD.

The Snap made for a pretty painless setup too, I've had problems with my setup of Plex in the past because of needing to manually add services, installing with plex user rather than pi user, and so on.

Anyone think it's worth to manually install or would the Snap work just as well? If manual is the way to go, does anyone have a current guide to do so? I don't have removable storage, the pi is running on the 14tb drive and rootfs has all the space.

Comment: Pls define "best"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.